# preg_match pattern for selecting variable name and key

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

help me to write `preg_match` pattern for selecting :

```
 1. array name
 2. array key
```

For example :
for `subject/string = "prop[4]"` , my `preg_match` must return

```
 1. prop (variable name)
 2. 4 (key of array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First group will match name, and second will match number: `/(\w+)\[(\d+)\]/`

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('/([a-z]+)\[([0-9]+)\]/i')
```